# Select portion of d3 chart

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 chart its hierarchy looks like this:

```
svg
   g <- this is row labels
   g <- this is col labels
   g <- this is actual chart
```

My problem is, I want to convert the actual chart part (3rd `<g>` element) to a png file without row and col labels.
So basically I need a d3.selection can select the `<svg>` element and its third `<g>` element only, the first 2 `<g>` are stripped from selection, so when this selection is converted to XML string and draw on `<canvas>`, there are no labels.

Currently I achieve by doing text processing over xml:

```
var source = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d3.select("svg").node());
var xmldoc = $.parseXML(source);
$(xmldoc).find("g:eq(1), g:eq(2)").remove();
var src2 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmldoc);
```

but I want to know if there are more convenient and elegant ways. Thanks.

Comment: Why not give the g elements class values and then select by class. Or unique ids and select by id.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to amend the SVG CSS selector from:

```
d3.select("svg")
```

to:

```
d3.select("svg > g:nth-child(3)")
```

This returns the third `<g>` tag belonging to the SVG parent, and would save you from having to remove the first two elements from the XML later on. Example showing the selection:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var g1 = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");
var g2 = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,50)");
var g3 = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(250,50)");
g1.append("rect").attr("id", 1).attr("width", 25).attr("height", 25).attr("fill", "purple");
g2.append("rect").attr("id", 2).attr("width", 25).attr("height", 25).attr("fill", "blue");
g3.append("rect").attr("id", 3).attr("width", 25).attr("height", 25).attr("fill", "orange");

var thirdGroup = d3.select("svg > g:nth-child(3)");

thirdGroup.select("rect")
  .transition().duration(600).ease("quad")
  .attr("width", 50).attr("height", 50);
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no answers I will post my solution here, not sure if it is the best way. Currently I achieve by doing text processing over xml:

```
var source = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d3.select("svg").node());
var xmldoc = $.parseXML(source);
$(xmldoc).find("g:eq(1), g:eq(2)").remove();
var src2 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmldoc);
```